# Delete multiple rows with ajax call in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using [Bootstrap Data Table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) and want to delete multiple users from the database. I am able to delete 1 user at a time with no problem but once I try to delete more than one I run into issues and I cannot find any errors.

Here is the AJAX code:

```
function removeRow(){

    var url = 'remove-user.php';
    var id = document.getElementById("user-id").value;
    var data = 'userID=' + id;
    
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            error: function(e){
                    alert(e);
                },
            success: function () {
                alert(data);
                var selects = $('#users-table').bootstrapTable('getSelections');
                    ids = $.map(selects, function (row) {
                        return row.id;
                    });

                $('#users-table').bootstrapTable('remove', {
                    field: 'id',
                    values: ids
                });                
            }
          });
    
    }
```

Example: The data in the url will be userID=1,2

Here is the remove-user.php code:

```
require("../config.php");
if(isset($_GET['userID'])) { 
  try{
    $userID = $_GET['userID'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN (:userID)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user_removed = 'User was successfully deleted.';
    $_SESSION['user_removed'] = $user_removed;
  } catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'The following error occured: <br/>'.$e->getMessage();
  }   
}
```

When I check more than one user the first user will get delete, but not the others. Are there any mistakes in my code?

Again, what I am looking to do is delete multiple users by selecting them from the table and passing the value of a hidden input which contains multiple ids like this - userID=1,2. When I go to the `remove-user.php` page directly and echo the GET it displays as 1,2 no quotes. If I change my delete to specify the IDs instead of binding a parameter everything works fine. I'm really not sure why its not working.

Please let me know if I need to give more info.

Comment: What does `$_GET['userID']` contain?

Comment: You pick the id by DOM-id. But there can be only one id.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it contains all the ids from the selected checkboxes and pass as a parameter in the URL like this - userID=1,2

Comment: Then you need to confirm that your query is being properly output.

Comment: Thanks! sorry is this is a stupid question, but exactly how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to find a solution which I thought I tried. I think the reason why it wasn't working might have something to do with me trying to use `bindParam`.

Here is what I changed my `remove-user.php` code to:

```
try{
    $ids = array($_GET['userID']);
    $inQuery = implode(',', $ids);
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        'DELETE
         FROM users
         WHERE user_id IN(' . $inQuery . ')'
    );
    $stmt->execute($ids);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $user_removed = ''.$count.' user(s) deleted successfully.';
    $_SESSION['user_removed'] = $user_removed;
} catch (Exception $e){
    $error = '<strong>The following error occured:</strong>'.$e->getMessage();
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're passing data to your PDOStatement.

```
// assign :userID to $userID which should be cast into an int.
$stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This is how I might approach similar (assuming that you have checked appropriate permissions):

```
$ids_in = $_GET['userID'];
$ids_cast = array();
foreach(explode(',', $ids_in) as $id) {
    // casting to an int means that SQL injection can't work, though I wonder if 
    // allowing a user to delete an arbitrary number of IDs is a good thing.
    $ids_cast[] = intval($id);
}
// gets rid of bad strings &ct.
$ids_filtered = implode(',',array_filter($ids_cast));
if(!$ids_filtered) die('No valid IDs');
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($ids_filtered)";
// run query.
```

Comment: how it prevent from deleting of an arbitrary number of ids?

Comment: @zavg `userID=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20,11,12,13,14,25` just seems destructive.

Comment: I tried the above answer and it still only deletes the first user selected not all.

Comment: You are passing userID as a comma separated list?

Comment: yea, the way the table works. I use a call `.bootstrapTable('getSelections')` and that adds the data to a hidden input as the value separated by comma.

Comment: Can you confirm that? What happens if you try to debug this file by accessing it directly?

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that the ids are being separated by comma.

Comment: OK. What happens if you try to navigate to this file by navigating to it directly?

Comment: The same thing happens. It will remove only the first ID. I was told by a friend to either use implode on the server side which is what your answer suggested or to create an array in JavaScript on the client side first before I pass it to the `remove-user.php` page. Don't really know how to do this so I am going to do some research, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query `:userID` parameter is string containing sequence of ids separated by comma (for example, `1,2`).

`$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN (:userID)";`

But when binding you define your parameter as integer passing `PDO::PARAM_INT` argument in `bindParam` function.

```
$stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Try to use

```
$stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

instead.

Comment: I tried the above answer and it still only deletes the first user selected not all.

Comment: can you confirm, that the GET['userId'] really contains the string "1,2" rather that just intended to be.
You pick the id by getElementById, which will usually be only one element. How do you concatenate and provide the intended elements to the string?

Comment: Additionally, PDO::PARAM_INT is definitivly the wrong datatype. Go on with PDO::PARAM_STR

Comment: Yea, when I go to the page directly and echo the `GET` it displays as `1,2` no quotes.