# Keep getting logged out after updating the database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056329/delete-multiple-rows-with-ajax-call-in-php?noredirect=1#comment44599611_28056329) about deleting multiple rows in the database and basically re-used the code to update multiple rows in the database, but now I am having issue once the database has been updated and the page refreshes it keeps loggin me out an I'm not sure why.

Here is the ajax:

```
function editUser(){

    var url = 'edit-user.php';
    var ids = document.getElementById("edit-user-id").value;
    var role = document.getElementById("role").value;
    var status = document.getElementById("accountStatus").value;
    var data = 'userID=' + ids.toString() + '&role=' + role + '&status=' + status;
    
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            error: function(e){
                    alert(e);
                },
            success: function () {
                var selects = $('#users-table').bootstrapTable('getSelections');
                    ids = $.map(selects, function (row) {
                        return row.id;
                    });
                $('#users-table').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                    silent: true
                });
                location.reload();                 
            }
          });
    
    }
```

And here is the PHP:

```
require("../config.php");
try{
    $role = $_GET['role'];
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $ids = array($_GET['userID']);
    $inQuery = implode(',', $ids);
    $query = 'UPDATE users SET role = :role, account_status = :status WHERE user_id IN ('.$inQuery.')';
    $query_params = array( 
        ':role' => $role,
        ':status' => $status
    ); 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    // Set variable message of affected rows
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $user_updated = ''.$count.' user(s) updated successfully.';
    $_SESSION['user_updated'] = $user_updated;
} catch (Exception $e){
    $error = '<strong>The following error occured:</strong>'.$e->getMessage();
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}
```

I tried changing `cache: true`, but that didn't work. Again, I do not want to be logged out. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I have narrowed it down to only happen when the page refreshes. I removed this piece of code `location.reload();` from the ajax call and it does not redirect me back to the login page, but if i hit F5 or click refresh it logs me out.

Comment: Do you cal session_start() at the top of your PHP file? I don't see it.

Comment: at the bottom of my `config.php` file I have `session_start()`.  The ajax and php are 2 separate files both of which have the `config.php` file

Comment: @iamthestreets, probably going to need to see how you are authenticated in order to see what the problem might be.

Comment: @Devon forgive me as I am still learning, but what do you mean exactly? I do have this piece of code at the top of my php page where the ajax is located: `if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
 $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    header("Location: ../index.php"); 
 die("Redirecting to: index.php");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I needed to move `session_start()` to the top of the `config.php` file to make sure that it is the very first thing called on the page. Everything seems to be working ok right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment:

Nothing is jumping out at me that would cause you to lose what is set in the `$_SESSION['user']`.  Try dumping `$_SESSION` on each page just to keep track of it and disable the redirect for now (just put an error message or something).  You can dump the array like so:

`print_r($_SESSION);`

Do you also know your prepared statement is broken?  I don't see the point of the array or the implode for `$ids` and `$inQuery`.  It should be something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'UPDATE users 
     SET role = ?, account_status = ?
     WHERE user_id = ?'
);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['role'], $_GET['status'], $_GET['userID']));
```

There is no point in using `IN` if you only have one entry.  You also aren't protecting your query from anything because you are still inserting the values into the prepare statement.

Comment: Thanks! I will give the `$_SESSION` dump a try. I do have multiple values, but it can be one as well. That's why i used `IN`. I am passing a parameter of all userids selected in the table and then updating each user.

Comment: So `$_GET['userID']` is an array?  Because `$ids = array($_GET['userID']);
    $inQuery = implode(',', $ids);` is never going to work.  You're defining an array in `$ids` with only a single element, then imploding it which is just going to return `$_GET['userID']` without any changes.

Comment: @iamthestreets: here is a sandbox example of what I'm talking about: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d97343f33e5d7cc0799caa385546acf9a3eb9efd.  It actually doesn't return the userid array at all, it breaks it because it expects a single dimensional array.

Comment: I have no problem with the way that works. The users are being updated in the database, but my problem is i keep getting logged out after the page reloads. I did update my code though.